# Comment Detector using regex with java

Tags: java, regex

I want to create beginning comment detector using regex with Java

I'm using `JTextArea` area to paste source code program and `JTextArea` comment as print out comment

```
Pattern aaa = Pattern.compile("(/\\*([^*]|[\\r\\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\\r\\n])))*\\*+/)|(//.*)");
Matcher bbb  =aaa.matcher(area.getText());

if(bbb.find())
{   
    comment.setText(bbb.group());
}
else
    System.out.println ("no found");
```

My input text :

```
start_code();
/****
* Common multi-line comment style.
****/
more_code(); 
/*
* Another common multi-line comment style.
*/
end_code();
```

but program result

```
/****
* Common multi-line comment style.
****/
```

I want this program printed all comment.

this is my complete code

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class regex extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JTextArea area;
    JTextArea comment1;
    JButton button1;

    public regex()
    {   
        super("program");
        tombol=new JButton("button1");
        area=new JTextArea();
        comment1=new JTextArea();
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        setLocation(200,200);
        setSize(1100,500);
        setLayout(null);
        area.setBounds(10,10,450,400);
        comment1.setBounds(480,10,450,400);
        button1.setBounds(10,410,450,25);
        add(area);
        add(comment1);
        add(button1);
        show();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(button1==e.getSource())
        {
            Pattern aaa=Pattern.compile("(/\\*([^*]|[\\r\\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\\r\\n])))*\\*+/)|(//.*)");
            Matcher bbb=aaa.matcher(area.getText());
            if(bbb.find())
            {   
                comment1.setText(bbb.group());
            }
            else
                System.out.println ("no found");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new regex();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this part:

```
if (bbb.find()) {
   comment1.setText(bbb.group());
}
```

to something like this:

```
while(bbb.find()) {
   comment1.setText(comment1.getText()+bbb.group()+"\n");
}
```

because bbb.find() gives you the next match back.

Also you could shorten your Regex String to this: "(?:/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*/]))*\*+/)|(?://.*)"

If you have more questions, just ask :)

Here the whole code, this works for me:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class RegexTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  JTextArea area;
  JTextArea comment1;
  JButton button1 = new JButton();
  private JButton tombol;

  public RegexTest() {
    super("program");
    tombol = new JButton("button1");
    area = new JTextArea();
    comment1 = new JTextArea();
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    setLocation(200, 200);
    setSize(1100, 500);
    setLayout(null);
    area.setBounds(10, 10, 450, 400);
    comment1.setBounds(480, 10, 450, 400);
    button1.setBounds(10, 410, 450, 25);
    add(area);
    add(comment1);
    add(button1);
    show();
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (button1 == e.getSource()) {
      Pattern aaa = Pattern.compile("(/\\*([^*]|[\\r\\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\\r\\n])))*\\*+/)|(//.*)");
      Matcher bbb = aaa.matcher(area.getText());
      while (bbb.find()) {
        comment1.setText(comment1.getText() + bbb.group() + "\n");
      }
      // if (bbb.find()) {
      // comment1.setText(bbb.group());
      // } else
      // System.out.println("no found");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new RegexTest();
  }
}
```

If you want to remove all comments:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (button1 == e.getSource()) {
      Pattern aaa = Pattern.compile("(/\\*([^*]|[\\r\\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\\r\\n])))*\\*+/)|(//.*)");
      Matcher bbb = aaa.matcher(area.getText());
      comment1.setText(bbb.replaceAll("")); //This is the new line

      // while (bbb.find()) {
      // comment1.setText(comment1.getText() + bbb.group() + "\n");
      // }
      // if (bbb.find()) {
      // comment1.setText(bbb.group());
      // } else
      // System.out.println("no found");
    }
  }
```

This is just a quick idea, if someone has something smarter, like removing the empty lines, please edit it in.

Comment: You are right about the loop. However there is one more problem with regexp. What if comment opening token `/*` will be inside of Java string? For example:  `String s = "/* test";  String s1 = "*/";`

Comment: Hm, you're right, but that would mean we have to implement something to make either the Strings regex-safe or use something described [here](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all matching groups:

```
if (bbb.find()) {
    StringBuilder comments = new StringBuilder();
    for (int g = 0; g < bbb.groupCount(); g++) {
        comments.append(bbb.group(g));
    }
    comment.setText(comments.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how if i want finding all method ?

example :

```
class example
{
    public void ex1()


    {
        statement;
    }
    private string ex2(int a)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    example(){
        statement;
    }
}
```

result program :

```
ex1() : void
ex2(a : int) : string
example()
```

using regex too.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question. You could try something like that, just place it in your class:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (button1 == e.getSource()) {
      Pattern aaa = Pattern.compile("(public|protected|private|static|\\s) +[\\w\\<\\>\\[\\]]+\\s+(\\w+) *\\([^\\)]*\\) *(\\{?|[^;])");
      Matcher bbb = aaa.matcher(area.getText());
      while (bbb.find()) {
        comment1.setText(comment1.getText() + bbb.group() + "\n");
      }
    }
  }
```

It doesn't format like your idea, but I think it does what you want.

And you shouldn't post new questions as answers, open a new one. And please mark a good answer as correct.